# MATLAB GUI and m file control components

Tags: matlab, user-interface, handle

I need to control the gui components via another m file, for example if i have some pushbutton i want to make him to be disable via some m file (not the gui m file but under the same workspace). The problem is that the m file not recognize the pushbutton(because it is a different file), so i can't use this command:

```
set(handle.pushbutton, 'Enable', 'off')
```

Do you have some idea to do it? i have tried to use global variable and it's not working..that's whay i've tried:

in the gui m file:

```
global h;
h=handle.pushbutton.
```

and in the other m file(not the gui m file):

```
global h;
set(h,'Enable', 'off');
```

Comment: You might be better with a long and unique name like GLOBAL_HANDLES just in case h is already in use, possibly being changed as the program runs. Long, standout names for globals is good practice anyway as they can cause lots of trouble.

Comment: You probably need to call [guidata](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) after you call set(h, 'enable','on')

Comment: Are you creating a GUI with Guide? And in case it matters, which version of MATLAB (they changed the graphics in r2014b, but it probably doesn't make any difference here).

Comment: yes with guide..r2012b

Answer (score 2):

You can use [findobj](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) to "find" the figure associated with your GUI from within the m file, get its children and access the pushbutton you want to disable, then disable it. In order to facilitate things, give a tag to each elements so that they are easy to find if need be.

As an example, let's say you give the name "MyFigure" to the figure of the GUI during its creation:

```
hfigure  = figure('Position',[100 100 200 100],'Units','normalized','name','MyFigure');
```

and give the tag "MyButton" to the pushbutton:

```
hButton1= uicontrol('Style','push','String','1','Position',[40 50 50 30],'Tag','MyButton');
```

Now in your m file, you can access this figure (note that it need to be opened) with this command:

```
F = findobj('Name','MyFigure');
```

Since all elements of your GUI are actually children of the main figure, you can access them with the "Children" property, again using `findobj`:

```
PushHandles = findobj(F.Children,'style','pushbutton','Tag','MyPushbutton')
```

You now have the handles to your pushbutton stored in `PushHandles`, which you can enable/disable as you wish:

```
set(PushHandles,'Enable','off');
```

yay!

Comment: I didn't understand the first command (hfigure=...), where should i put it?

Comment: Are you using GUIDE? If so, you can simply edit the GUI's name in the property inspector.

Comment: yes..ok and to put all the other commands in the m file? because i have tried it and i got an error.
this how it looks like in the m file(the name is GUI):
F = findobj('Name','GUI');
PushHandles=findobj(F.Children,'style','pushbutton','Tag','pushbutton1');
                       set(PushHandles,'Value','off');

Comment: Oh I made a mistake! To disable a pushbutton you  need to use `set(PushHandles,'Enable','off')`. That should work now

Comment: i changed it before..it still not working
The error is: "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array".
The command is: PushHandles = findobj(F.Children,'style','pushbutton','Tag','MyPushbutton')

Comment: oh you might want to use `get(F,'Children')` instead of `F.Children`. This happens because of the Matlab release you're using

Comment: remove the PushHandles=... and to put get(F, 'Children')? because it not work

Comment: I cannot make findobj work like this. Please see my anser below for a clumsy alternative. Can you please suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation of Benoit's answer.

I have a gui created in Guide called 'TheGui'. It is saved in files TheGui.fig and TheGui.m. TheGui has one button with tag 'TheGuiButton'.

A the MATLAB command line, I start the gui with the command TheGui and it opens.

The with this loop in MATLAB command window, I get a handle to 'TheGui'. I could not make F = findobj('Name','TheGui') work.

```
for hx = findall(0, 'type','figure'),if isequal('TheGui',get(hx,'name')),hGui=hx,end,end
```

With a handle to TheGui, I get a handle to the pushbutton (the only child).

```
hButton = findobj(hGui,'style','pushbutton')
```

I can see that this is what I want by examining its properties with

```
v = get(hButton)
```

And I can change the properties of the button like this

```
set(hButton,'enable','off')
```

I put it all together in an MATLAB script file to see it work

```
for hx = findall(0, 'type','figure')
  if isequal('TheGui',get(hx,'name'))
    hGui=hx
  end
end
hButton = findobj(hGui,'style','pushbutton')
for i = 1:10
  set(hButton,'enable','off')
  pause(1)
  set(hButton,'enable','on')
  pause(1)
end
```

Comment: ok it works now but why you use for loop and if? i put it without the for loop and it's work..
i write only this command: hGui = findall(0, 'type','figure')

Comment: You might have more than one figure, especially if your program makes many plots.

Comment: but in my program the gui is the first figure

Comment: You a making an assumption that may not alway be true. I wouldn't do that if it is easy to work around the assumption.